# Trying to deploy a Ruby/Reactapp on Vercel - it fails to build the PG gem but I still have it in my gemfile

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, deployment, vercel

I have a full stack app that uses Ruby/PostgreSQL on the back end, and React on the front end. I'm trying to deploy, but it says:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /vercel/path0/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/pg-1.5.4/ext
```

Then it's just stuff concerning the gemfile, which doesn't make too much sense to me.

I tried using `bundle update` with `bundle install`, reinstalling `postgres` and changing file versions. I also looked at the database.yml, environment.rb, and I'm not really sure what else I can do.

The top of my gemfile is as follows:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.4"

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem "pg", "~> 1.1"
```

Any experience with using Vercel and React would be much appreciated.

Comment: I’d add “all the stuff about the gem file” and the lines before the error to your question.